# How to pull specific data from comma separated .txt file and apply it to a variable to use in command line switch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have hundrends of subfolders with identical file structures. One of the files in each folder is a metadata.txt file that contains comma separated information. I need to pull the 8th value and asign it to a variable %x and then use that variable as a switch in a follow-up command.

The metadata.txt file looks like this:

```
91,Chocolate,10,Large,Easy Bake Oven,350,0,39.9475,Cake,1.0.0.1,C:\CakeRecords,2044449,2(10-50),1,
```

Step 1: Assign varariable x (%x) the 8th value in the data. In this case it's 39.9475

Step 2: Run EasyBake command using the variable as a switch
Example: `EasyBake.exe 39.9475`

I'll be running this command one time in the root folder and having it go through every subfolder to run the command in each of them. I've already run a command to create a new folder 'NewRecipe' in each of the subfolders, so I've got a decent idea on how to bounce between folders to run the scripts, but any advice would be appreciated there as well.

```
FOR /d %A IN ("N:\old recipes\*") DO mkdir "%A\NewRecipe"
```

Comment: `for /D %A in ("N:\old recipes\*") do for /F "usebackq tokens=8 delims=," %X in ("%~A\metadata.txt") do echo %X` extracts the eighth value of all the `metadata.txt` files...

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense, why create a directory inside every top level directory in old recipes called newrecipes? The last place I'm going to look for a new recipe inside a chapter of a book on old recipes! Additionally you have provided a command which ran in the command prompt, what are you wanting with regards a solution because if you are wanting a batch file at least three of your tags are there for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\metadata.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%filename1%" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=8delims=," %%t IN ("%%a") DO (
 ECHO take your choice
 ECHO PUSHD "%%~dpa"
 ECHO MD newrecipe
 ECHO easybake.exe %%t
 ECHO POPD 
 ECHO ================
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Simply shows the required instructions.

Find each of the target files, get the appropriate field to `%%t`, then do what you will with the appropriate elements of `%%a`